# Making a graphical population map from tables

Tags: java, dictionary, population

I have table 10x10 filled with two populations. The populations migrate and change the positions on the map. Two populations can be in one cell.

I need the suggestion what can I use that will graphically illustrate this two populations (population 1 - red, population 2 - blue) at simple map?

Comment: we can not do anything without code.

Comment: MathLAB does such a things on the fly)